# Please help reframe this question

Tags: support, specific-question

My [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/131218/85534) received a silent downvote.  Would appreciate a suggestion for how to reframe it (to improve it) or where to post it instead of Web Applications.

The question is:

> I don't have a television. How can I watch the presidential debate as
>   it's happening? How about the hour-long preparation NBC is going to
>   broadcast right before the debate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How would you reframe that? You're essentially asking for a recommendation for an app that would allow you watch something on TV without a television. Questions asking for recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Try [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) or maybe the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=politics.stackexchange.com) at [Politics Stack Exchange](https://politics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks, will do.